# How does the default browser on Android send "SEND" intents?

Tags: java, android

I'd like to enable a "silent send" from my application-- that is, I'd like to catch the SEND intent in a Service, not an Activity. How does the default Android web browser send that intent? Is it possible to handle it in a Service, or in an Activity that never sets a View?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to handle it in a
>   Service, or in an Activity that never
>   sets a View?

`ACTION_SEND` `Intents` are sent as activity intents (e.g., `startActivity()`), and so you cannot have a `Service` receive them. You can have them handled by an `Activity` that never calls `setContentView()`, though.

Comment: Wireless Designs has an opposing answer (below). I'm not sure who's right... I'll just have to try both. Thanks!