# How to handle a silent SEND intent with a headless activity

Tags: java, android

Just as the user who asked this: [How does the default browser on Android send "SEND" intents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320930/how-does-the-default-browser-on-android-send-send-intents), I want my Android app to process a silent send. I implemented the proposed solution, a headless activity that never calls setContentView():

```
public class IntentMgrAct extends Activity {
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // setContentView explicitally ommited
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
}
```

When other apps send the intent to my "dumb" activity, it shows up behind the toast, but all I want is the toast. I tried to hide the headless activity with finish() after Toast.makeText and does the trick, but there is a noticeable flicker. How can I prevent the the activity from showing up?

Comment: I know it's doable, Read It Later for example only shows a toast when sending a link to it from other apps

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"` to your `<activity>` element in the manifest.

Comment: Is there any equivalent available in AppCompat? My Project's BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity. Hence I forced to use AppCompat.