# Headless Activity on Android that has a Viewmodel

Tags: android, viewmodel, mvp

I am creating some geofences. In order to remove them later, I have to hang on to the `Intent` that they were created with.

Figured I would store that in a `ViewModel` and attach it to a headless `Activity`. Was psyched when I found this: [How to handle a silent SEND intent with a headless activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796118/how-to-handle-a-silent-send-intent-with-a-headless-activity). However, you have to call `finish()` on the activity, which I am thinking will result in the Viewmodel being discarded as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to keep the `Intent` itself to remove the Geofences and what you're trying to do would not work.

The [removeGeofences API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingClient.html#removeGeofences(android.app.PendingIntent)) takes a [`PendingIntent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent). When comparing two PendingIntents to see if they are equal, they follow the rules of [Intent.filterEqual()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#filterEquals(android.content.Intent)):

> Determine if two intents are the same for the purposes of intent resolution (filtering). That is, if their **action, data, type, class, and categories are the same.** This does not compare any extra data included in the intents.

As long as you can construct an Intent with the same information as before, you can construct a new `PendingIntent` and still have it match.

Or, you could use the [removeGeofences()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingClient.html#removeGeofences(java.util.List%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)) method that takes the String request IDs, which you can add to your Geofence via [setRequestId()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Geofence.Builder#setRequestId(java.lang.String)). Then you only need to keep track of Strings in order to cancel Geofences.

Comment: By the 'what you are trying to do' you mean you cannot have a headless activity with a viewmodel?

Comment: That's too bad. Thanks.